# While loops and condition satisfaction

Tags: while-loop

```
x = 5 
y = 4
while x >=1: 
    x = x - 1; 
    y = y*2; 
    print ("x is", (x), end='')
    print("")
    print ("y is", (y), end='')
    print("")
```

Gives the following output:

x is 4.
y is 8.
x is 3.
y is 16.
x is 2.
y is 32.
x is 1.
y is 64.
x is 0.
y is 128.

Why does it run the loop even when X is 0? It seems like it should stop with x = 1 and y = 64. I realize I'm just missing some fundamental, any explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: You go through the loop process when x = 1, because that is >= 1. But then you decrement x which would make it 0. Same thought with y, you'd multiply it by two on the last pass. You have to remember it will loop as long as you meet the condition, what happens inside the loop will still process. It only stops once the condition is no longer true, which is the case when x = 0

Answer (score 1):

In the last loop iteration the value of x is one not zero, you make it zero in next line."x=x-1"

```
x = 5 
y = 4
while x >=1:  // x = 1 which is valid value
    x = x - 1; // then x -1 = 0 
    y = y*2; 
    print ("x is", (x), end='')
    print("")
    print ("y is", (y), end='')
    print("")
```

If you don't want zero, condition will be `while x > 1`